# Modal dialog box div is not working in IE browser?

Tags: html, css

I need help for modal dialog box is not working in I.E browser here is my code please verify and where i did a mistake suggest me.It is working in Firefox and chrome but I.E is not working.Please verify my below code and give me a suggestion for me.

```
HTML code:
<a href='#openModal' ><img src='images/question.png' /> </a>
<div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>
    <div>
        <a href='#close' title='Close' class='close'>X</a>
        <img src='images/ifsc-code1.png' />
    </div>
</div>
CSS code:
    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: -1;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;

        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 604px;
        //height: 600px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 5% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        -moz-box-shadow: -5px -5px 30px #888888,5px 5px 30px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow:-5px -5px 30px #888888 ,5px 5px 30px #888888;
        box-shadow: -5px -5px 30px #888888,5px 5px 30px #888888;        
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }
    .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

Comment: It has a opacity of 0, so unless you change that with JS it shouldn't be visible in any browser (supporting opacity of course ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is perfectly working for me in IE9, IE10, Firefox and Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
   <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
   <meta name="Description" content="">
  <style>
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: -1;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;

    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 604px;
    //height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px -5px 30px #888888,5px 5px 30px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-5px -5px 30px #888888 ,5px 5px 30px #888888;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 30px #888888,5px 5px 30px #888888;        
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
  </style>

  </head>

  <body>
 <a href='#openModal' ><img src='images/question.png' /> </a>
 <div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>
    <div>
         <a href='#close' title='Close' class='close'>X</a>
         <img src='images/ifsc-code1.png' />
     </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working but close popup not close even click on close button in I.E@
Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: Here is my website url plese check once in I.e it is working in firefox and chrome but not working in I.E https://www.rummyno1.com/withdraw_cash.php @Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: it is throwing alert message when i open the site. is it the correct one?

Comment: Thanq for response the above code is working perfect from I.E-9 and all browsers @ Suresh Ponnukalai

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>

  <style>
.pop-up {position:absolute; top:0; left:-500em}
.pop-up:target {position:static; left:0;}

.popBox {
  background:#ffffff;

  position:absolute; left:30%; right:30%; top:30%; bottom:30%;

  z-index:1;
    border:1px solid #3a3a3a; 
  -moz-border-radius:12px;
  border-radius:12px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #3a3a3a;
  -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #3a3a3a;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #3a3a3a;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
:target .popBox {position:fixed; opacity:1;}

.popBox:hover {box-shadow:3px 3px 6px #5a5a5a;}
  .lightbox {display:none; text-indent:-200em; background:#000; opacity:0.4; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;}
:target .lightbox {display:block}
  .close {
  position:absolute; top:-0.75em; right:-0.75em; display:block; width:1em; height:1em;
  font:bold large/1 arial, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;
  background:#000; border:3px solid #fff; color:#fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #3a3a3a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #3a3a3a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #3a3a3a;
}
.close:before {content:"X"}
.close:hover {box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #c00; background:#c00;}
.close span {text-indent:-200em; display:block;}
  </style>

  </head>

  <body>
  <ul id="links">
  <li><a href="#pop3">Pop-up Two</a></li>
</ul>
 <div id="pop3" class="pop-up">
  <div class="popBox">
    <div>
      <h2>Pop-up Two</h2>
      <p>Blah, blah, blah. Yada, yada, yada.</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="close"><span>Close</span></span></a>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The above code is working in all browsers from I.E-9